# Can I filter queries within an IQueryable with a join table in .net core 3.1

Tags: linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an `IQueryable` as a filter function with multiple inputs (I have excluded some for clarity):

```
public IActionResult Index(... searchType, string searchUndertype ...)
{
    var query = _context.ProjektDokument
                        .Include(p => p.Dokumenttype)
                        .Include(p => p.DokuUndertype)
                        ...
                        .AsQueryable();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchType))
    {
        query = query.Where(p => p.Dokumenttype.Dokumenttype1.Contains(searchType));
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchUndertype))
    {
        query = query.Where(p => p.DokuUndertype.DokuUndertype1.Contains(searchUndertype));
    }

    return View(query.ToList());
}
```

This works perfectly. Now, the users want to add a functionality, where the results in the input box for either Dokumenttype1 or DokuUndertype1 gets filtered by the other so only DokumenttypeDokuUndertype pairs, that are already created, get selected in either input box, e.g. if you select A in dokumenttype1, you only get all instances where A is in dokumenttype1 and vice versa.

To that end I created a join table:

```
public partial class DokumenttypeDokuUndertype
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int DokumenttypeId { get; set; }
    public int DokuUndertypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual DokuUndertype DokuUndertype { get; set; }
    public virtual Dokumenttype Dokumenttype { get; set; }
}
```

My question is, how do I go about this? I have tried including the join table in the variable query by boolean operators, but to no avail. I have tried `.ThenInclude`, and have struck out again. I thought maybe a view model could be the way to go but do not quite know how to go about it.

Do any of you have any suggestions? (I have used a database first approach)

Comment: Does this answer your. question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65107560/10646316

Comment: It didn't, but it did give me the following idea: `query.Include(p => p.Dokumenttype).ThenInclude(p => p.DokumenttypeDokuUndertype).Where(p => p.Dokumenttype.Dokumenttype1.Contains(searchType)));` This at least doesn't throw an error, so not a step in the wrong direction just maybe not one in the right either